# How to change SwipeRefreshLayout's progress background color without a color resource?

Tags: android

So, SwipeRefreshLayout has this method called "setProgressBackgroundColor(int colorRes)" that takes a color resource (R.color.myColor). Works fine. But in my project, I want to parse a color from a string and use said color. How can I do that?

Answer (score 16):

According to the lastest version, you can now use `SwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(int color)`  : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(int)

From a sring color, you can use it like this :

```
int myColor = Color.parseColor("#ff00ff");
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(myColor);
```

Make sure you are using the latest `android-support-v4` lib.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue very similar to one SwipeRefreshLayout had when it was still a horizontal progress bar, and the fix will need to come from Google, same as the previous one. I've filed an issue on the android tracker for it.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78531

Once SwipeRefreshLayout has the proper method, you can use `Color.parseColor(String color)` to parse your string into a color value that the currently-nonexistent method could use.

Answer (score -1):

You would need some way of associating a string to a certain color resource. Create some kind of parser that recognizes the string "orange" means you should access the color resource "R.color.myOrange" for example. And then setProgressBackgroundColor(R.color.myOrange) as you've already mentioned. It's hard to give more advice without more information on what you're looking for.

Comment: Im looking for a way to create a resource in execution time. I can't have the color inserted beforehand in my resources. As I said, I will receive a string and parse it as a color to use it.